# Numpy Manipulating all but one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an N x N Numpy array.
I need to manipulate the ith column in a paricular way, and the remaining columns in a different but common way. How do i do this in a numpythonic manner. The parameter i is passed to the function to be used.

Example:

```
a=np.zeros([4,4])
```

Now, we need 1st,2nd and 4th, say to be squared element wise.
3rd one to be cubed elementwise.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It's impossible to answer unless you show us *how* you expect the array to manipulated. Please include an example.

Comment: added an example @ajcr

Comment: @NilsWerner , tried creating a duplicating and manupalating that and then finally using the result, seems quite inefficient to me

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Squaring and cubing your array of zeros does nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
most_of_the_result = do_whatever(numpy.delete(arr, col_index, axis=1))
insertion_column = do_other_thing(arr[:, col_index])

result = numpy.insert(most_of_the_result, col_index, insertion_column, axis=1)
```

or

```
result = do_whatever(arr)
special_column = do_other_thing(arr[:, col_index])
result[:, col_index] = special_column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of numbers to select the columns you want to manipulate. For example you could say:

```
a[:,(0,1,3)] = a[:,(0,1,3)]**2
```

to square column 1, 2, and 4. Remember they are indexed from zero.

More generally if you only want to manipulate all but column `X`, then you could

```
sel = range(a.shape[1])
sel.remove(X)
a[:, sel] = a[:, sel]**2
```

Comment: array is very large, and the column not be selected is passed as a parameter

Comment: Well that is some new information. Can't you pass the set as a parameter? Lets say you want to remove column `X`, then you could do something like `sel = range(N)`, then `sel.remove(X)`. Where `N` is the large number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Since raising 0s to any power is still 0, let's use 2s.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.full((4, 4), 2.0)
a[:, 2] = a[:, 2]**3
ci = [i for i in range(a.shape[1]) if i != 2]
a[:, ci] = a[:, ci]**2
```